# Word for an animal that has been ridden too much?

Tags: single-word-requests, simile

Example:

> That man is as tired as a [...] donkey.

I thought of the word *overridden* but I think it means something else.

Comment: There's the idiom *dog-tired*

Comment: *...as a donkey that has been ridden to the ground*?

Comment: Use a hyphen. Over-ridden or ridden-out.

Comment: In that particular sentence "whipped" or "beaten" would work sorta OK.

Comment: Has this donkey been ridden too much over his lifetime, or ridden too much today?

Comment: Broke-back. I'll get my coat.

Comment: Animal who has been ridden too much? _Yo mamma!_

Comment: Over-utilized may be

Comment: PETA would call such an animal "an animal".

Comment: Just to make my point crystal clear; **as a knackered donkey** doesn't work. Please see [Ngram chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as+a+knackered+donkey%2Che%27s+knackered%2C+overworked+donkey&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=6&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che%20%27s%20knackered%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coverworked%20donkey%3B%2Cc0) and click on *search books*

Comment: Here in the Southern US we have a saying: "beaten like a rented mule," that I find more and more appropriate all the time.

Comment: As per @Geobits comment I feel there must be a term for when a horse has been used on one ride for too long that might not apply to an animal that has been worn out by a lifetime of use.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you don't mind using a term usually confined to British English, try *knackered*. From TheFreeDictionaryOnline.com:

> **knackered** *adj*
>   1. exhausted; tired out
>   2. worn out; no longer working, esp after long or hard use

Comment: The OP may be unaware that this expression does *not* fit in his sentence: "That man is as tired as a [knackered] donkey."

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Sure it fits. Why can't you have a knackered donkey?

Comment: Yes, you can have a knackered donkey but to say "He is as tired as a knackered donkey", sounds unfamiliar. It's not a common collocation. I *like* knackered, it's a great word. But I'd use it differently.

Comment: So you've gone from "does *not* fit his sentence" to "I'd use it differently?"

Comment: I might say something similar to: *I felt as knackered as a donkey that had been working in the mines.*

Comment: BTW, I'll add that *knackered* is such a terrific term I wish America would adopt it wholesale.

Comment: I second @Mari-LouA's comment. To me, "knackered" is a very close synonym for "tired," so pasting "knackered" into the OP's sentence would result in a sentence that basically reads, "That man is as tired as a [tired] donkey." Sure, it makes sense, but unless it's supposed to be part of a *Blackadder* script, it may not have quite the sound the OP is looking for...

Comment: I always thought knackered was what happened to the old nags at the glue factory.

Comment: @Robusto In this case, it would make more sense to say _"That man is knackered."_ than _"... as tired as a knackered donkey."_

Comment: I don't have the rep to downvote this answer but I see an obvious problem. The word knackered has very specific connotations for a horse. The word 'knackered' comes from the term 'knackers yard' which is where you would send a horse to be killed. So in saying a horse is 'knackered' the implication is that you sent it to be killed.

Comment: @Rudi: The etymology of a term, while interesting, does not necessarily affect its current usage. For example, "cheap" has come to mean shoddy, but its etymology shows a more favorable pedigree. By your reasoning, you couldn't use the term "bullshit" unless you were talking about actual manure, a position I reject.

Comment: @Rudi if that were the case, the word _sycophant_, for example, [should mean](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=sycophant&allowed_in_frame=0) one who falsely accuses others,. Etymology is fascinating but does not always affect effect the current meaning of a word.

Comment: @Robusto - No, but if I used the word bullshit to refer to cow manure you would see the confusion. That is the level of the link here. When you knacker a horse, you kill it. So saying a horse is knackered can either mean you killed it or it is tired. If a cow shit in your house you could say it's bullshit but it would be confusing. That is the nature of my objection. Etymology aside, knacker is still an in-use verb for killing an animal and the typical association is a horse.

Comment: @Rudi: I'm still left with the feeling that you wish to disallow all figurative uses of language, even those that have become detached from their original meanings.

Comment: Furthermore, consider the word *slaughter*. We commonly speak of one sports team *slaughtering* the other team, but we don't mean they literally killed, drained, and dressed the carcasses of the other team's players. That is a direct analogue to *knackered* here.

Comment: @Rudi Why is that specific connotation inappropriate? That *is* what happens to a horse that is ridden too hard, as the question is asking. Horses are delicate, and hard riding kills them at worst, and at best lames them—at which point they're *knackered*, literally sent to the knacker's yard, because a lame horse is useless.

Comment: @Robusto - That isn't a direct analogue to my example or this one. When a football team gets 'slaughtered' it is obvious what your implying. But if you take a pig to a competition and it ended up getting 'slaughtered', then it becomes ambiguous. I'm not saying don't use the word at all, I am just saying it's ambiguous. I asked three local horse riders what they thought and one said they thought knackered implied the horse was *due* for the slaughtering yard, one that it had been slaughtered already, and the other that it was tired/knackered in the colloquial sense. It's ambiguous.

Answer (score 13):

A common adjective would be ***worn-out***. (as in *worn-out donkey*).

> (Of a person or animal) extremely tired; exhausted:
>
> <sup>http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/worn-out</sup>

Note: *Worn-out horse* is more common than *worn-out donkey*. Personally, I heard or read *worn-out horse* more than *worn-out donkey* also.

Below [Ngram comparison](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=worn-out%20horse%2Cworn-out%20donkey%2Cworn-out%20mule&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cworn%20-%20out%20horse%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cworn%20-%20out%20donkey%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cworn%20-%20out%20mule%3B%2Cc0) ( between *worn-out horse, worn-out donkey, worn-out mule*) might give an idea also but it doesn't prove how widely accepted the terms are in general:

[image: Google Books Ngram showing *worn-out horse* being more prevalent than *worn-out donkey* and *worn-out mule*]

Example:

> Under fire, he "hugged the ground more than once," fatigue knocked him out, and sometimes he collapsed like "a worn-out horse."
>
> *[Under the Bombs: The German Home Front, 1942-1945 By Earl Ray Beck (1986)]*

---

As an additional information, it is more common to use "as tired as an <*animal noun*>" phrase without using an adjective before the animal noun. Though, it seems like this usage has fallen dramatically. *Dog* is still more common than *donkey* or *horse*.

Below [NGram comparison](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as%20tired%20as%20a%20*%2C&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cas%20tired%20as%20a%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bas%20tired%20as%20a%20dog%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bas%20tired%20as%20a%20pack%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bas%20tired%20as%20a%20donkey%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bas%20tired%20as%20a%20man%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bas%20tired%20as%20a%20horse%3B%2Cc0) might give an idea also: (Note: I searched **as tired as a ***, asterisk character is a wildcard. I tried searching **tired as a * donkey** or **tired as a * horse** but I didn't get any results.)

[image: Google Books Ngram showing use of *as tired as a dog*, *as tired as a horse*, and similar phrases for other animals]

As Mari-Lou A suggested in the comments, *dog-tired* is more common than any of these as an animal-related term to indicate exhaustion.

Answer (score 12):

My favorite expression: "That man's been rode hard and put away wet."

Answer (score 9):

Old worn-out nags used to be called *jades*. Jaded might be a good word, depending on your context.

Comment: This would have been the best answer 150 years ago. Webster's _Dictionary of the American Language_ (1852) specifically identifies the transitive verb _jade_ as meaning "To tire; to fatigue; to weary with hard service; as, to _jade_ a horse" and the adjective _jaded_ as meaning "Tired; wearied; fatigued; harassed." But more recently, _jaded_ in the sense of cynical or world-weary has overwhelmed the word's earlier meaning and makes it less commonly understood in that sense. Still, +1 for bringing up this highly relevant term.

Comment: Oops—my comment above should have referred to Webster's _American Dictionary of the English Language_ (1852). I must be getting knackered (or jaded).

Answer (score 7):

> Tired as an [overworked](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/overworked) donkey

> 1. *To force to work too hard or too long*.

Answer (score 7):

Another word for worn out is *spent*. [The Free Dictionary](http://thefreedictionary.com/spent) includes multiple references to being exhausted, depleted of energy, tired, and worn out.

Answer (score 5):

You could use *hackneyed*, pronounced `/ˈhæknɪd/`.  Here are two senses for it:

> 2. Used so frequently and indiscriminately as to have lost its freshness and interest; made trite and commonplace; stale.
> 3. Habituated by much practice, experienced; sometimes with the ulterior idea of disgust or weariness.

*Hackneyed* is especially appealing due to its obvious derivation from *hackney*, a word used since Chaucer and before for equines of a middling nature.   It was later were used for equines available for hire, as in a *hackney horse, hackney ass, hackney mule*, all given by the OED.  Using the word *hackneyed* lends connotative weight to the sense of something that’s now in a bad way as a result of having been used so much over its lifetime of service.

For alternatives, there is also the compound adjective *time-worn*, which means:

> Worn by process of time; impaired by age.

For simpler terms, you could also turn to *shabby*, *tired*, *worn-out*, *run-down*, or *broken-down*.  Those should work just fine as well.  Maybe even *disused* (but see below for the noun *desuetude*).

For longer, more Latinate terms, *decrepit* might work too, but probably not *dilapidated* except in figurative use since it has no stones to lose.  The uncommon noun *desuetude* in common use means:

> The condition or state into which anything falls when one ceases to use or practise it; the state of disuse.

And has come to have a [legal meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desuetude) as well.  But if you write that your donkey has lapsed into desuetude, many readers will have to look the word up. :)

---

<sub>All definitions taken from the OED.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

***Spavined.*** Per free college dictionary:

> Adj.  1.  spavined - (of horses) afflicted with a swelling of the hock-joint
>   unfit - not in good physical or mental condition; out of condition; "fat and very unfit"; "certified as unfit for army service"; "drunk and unfit for service"
>   <sub>Based on WordNet 3.0, Farlex clipart collection. © 2003-2012 Princeton University, Farlex Inc.</sub>

But when I've seen this word used in a literal sense, it's almost always applied to horses. You might see a reference to something else, like stairs, being *spavined*, but that's a metaphor drawing upon the veterinary term.

Comment: I wouldn't use this when talking about tiredness- I have only ever heard it used in a specific veterinary context and there it means unsound rather than exhausted.

Answer (score 2):

Another option that could work in place of over-ridden is "foundered".

From http://www.thefreedictionary.com/foundering:

> foun·der 1  (foundr)
>   v. foun·dered, foun·der·ing, foun·ders
>
> v.intr.
>
> 1. To sink below the surface of the water: The ship struck a reef and foundered.
> 2. To cave in; sink: The platform swayed and then foundered.
> 3. To fail utterly; collapse: a marriage that soon foundered.
> 4. To stumble, especially to stumble and go lame. Used of horses.
> 5. To become ill from overeating. Used of livestock.
> 6. To be afflicted with laminitis. Used of horses.
>
> v.tr. To cause to founder.
>
> n. See laminitis.
>
> [Middle English foundren, to sink to the ground, from Old French fondrer, from Vulgar Latin *funderre, from *fundus, *funder-, bottom, from Latin fundus, fund-.]

In this particular instance road founder would be the cause of an animal that was ridden too much and it applies specifically to horses/donkeys.

Answer (score 1):

A donkey or horse that has been ridden out is hobbled.

> **hobble** ([*definition from Merriam-Webster*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hobble))
>
> 1. to walk with difficulty because of injury or weakness
> 2. to slow the movement, progress, or action of (someone or something)

Comment: I added in the definition from the dictionary for everyone's reference. Alas, I have too much reputation, so my edits are automatically approved, but if you disagree with the edit, feel free to roll back my changes.

Comment: No, it isn't. A hobble is a specific piece of equipment for tying up either one or two legs of an animal to stop it wandering too far overnight when you don't have a fenced off area or stable. This gives us the human term "hobbling" meaning walking unevenly or with a stilted stride which relates to the restricted movement of a hobbled equine. It certainly wouldn't make sense in the phrase suggested in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

It's clear there's no cliche answer to this question, though I would support "worn-out" as the most apt and common description of a donkey that's been ridden too much. But if there's no cliche, and we are committed not just to common and correct usage, then why not go with something more interesting:

**busted**

As in: "The man is as tired as a busted donkey."

Please don't respond by saying that "busted" only applies to machines, equipment, and other inorganic things.

Comment: Rather than simply telling people what to do, it would be better if you demonstrated why they shouldn't do it.

Comment: There is a bit of a complication with the word _busted_: It was (and may still be) sometimes used as a synonym for _broken_ in referring to training a horse (or donkey) to accept a rider. That's why the term _bronco buster_ describes someone who 'breaks" horses to the saddle.

Answer (score 1):

How about dilapidated?

*That man is as tired as a dilapidated donkey.*

> **dilapidated** ([*definition from Merriam-Webster*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dilapidated))
>
> 1. in very bad condition because of age or lack of care

In the synonyms there was also moth-eaten. *'That man is as tired as a moth-eaten donkey'* sounds pretty sonorous to me, but it might not be the most common expression!

Answer (score 0):

To me the best fit from existing language is **hard-ridden** or **hard ridden**.

Answer (score 0):

I might go for [swaybacked](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/swaybacked). Technically speaking, it just refers to *having an abnormally hollow or sagging back*, but it carries the connotation that the swayed back is due to overloading and overwork.

Answer (score 0):

How about the phrase "About as worn out as a government mule" ?

Answer (score 0):

***Well-worn*** implies some physical deterioration. ***Haggard*** implies more severe deterioration. I don't think there are nouns that describe what you're thinking, only adjectives.